# delete entity that map with another entity

Tags: java, hibernate, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

entity A --> id, entity_a_name, foreign_key_entity_B
entity B ---> id, entity_b_name

when i delete entity B record, it suppose to auto delete  entity A that has foreign_key_entity_B  ?

```
Error: ORA-02292: integrity constraint (schema.FKA630D2FB5F0F1180) violated - child record found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well most Oracle databases I've seen don't auto-delete child records or anything. So you should delete all child records before you can delete you parent record.

Comment: smart you know i'm using oracle =)  mean no workaround other than manually delete child

Comment: Well you could always look into cascade delete as a workaround but I don't really have alot any experience with it myself but I think it should be used with caution, any mistakes could result in unwanted data loss ;-)